# how do i enable Asynch Module/Http on IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, scaling, wcf

I am trying to enable WCF to scale out using Asycn pattern, it is a configuration setting, to enable asynch processing, but i can't find out where this is. I think it was in .net 3.5 SP1 feature, but there isn't much on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the registration manually or you can use this tool [WcfAsyncWebUtil.exe](http://blogs.msdn.com/wenlong/attachment/8856601.ashx)  from this Blog [The .NET Endpoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/endpoint/archive/2008/08/14/orcas-sp1-improvement-asynchronous-wcf-http-module-handler-for-iis7-for-better-server-scalability.aspx)

Comment: this is great, excet i am not sure how to do it manually.  I like when people provide tools but that blog post doesn't really specify what it is doing, other than providing a tool.